Why did Longinus and Cassius change form?
In Evangelion: 3.0 You Can (Not) Redo, Kaworu and Shinji go to retrieve the spears of  Longinus and Cassius to try and reset the world. However, Kaworu notices the spears have changed form and are now identical to each other.

Kaworu: Wait a minute. Something's not right.
Shinji: What is it, Kaworu?
Kaworu: This is strange. The two spears have changed shape to resemble each other.

[...]

Shinji: No! If we had those spears, we could start everything over!
Kaworu: We need a matched set of spears, Cassius and Longinus. Instead, all we have here are two identical spears.

Transcript from Subs Like Script
Why did the Spears of Cassius and Longinus transform to resemble each other?
